# JS: proper way of using optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am just trying to understand at what level of an object to use optional chaining.  If I have the given object

```
foo: {
    other: {
        name: "Bill"
    }
}
```

rather than do this:

```
if (foo && foo.other && foo.other.name) { ... }
```

I want to use optional chaining but I always finding myself just adding `?.` at every level.

would the proper way be to add it to every level like this:

```
if (foo?.other?.name) {

}
```

or can you leave the last one out since that will result in false if it's not there:

```
if (foo?.other.name) {

}
```

Comment: If `other` is `undefined` then `foo?.other.name` will throw a type error, whereas `foo?.other?.name` will not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add the `?` at *every* level where the preceding key can return a `null` value.

```
const ohNo = this?.data?.set?.can?.break?.at?.any?.level;
```

If you were to leave out any `?` in there, you'd get null reference exceptions when the preceding depth level is `null`...